# Issue working with numbers in Javascript

Tags: javascript, numbers

I'm new in developing javascript apps, i have a doubt about a behaviour that i'm going to try to explain.

If i execute:

```
Number(5555555555555555);
```

**Result:** 5555555555555555

But if i execute:

```
Number(55555555555555555);
```

**Result:** 55555555555555550

Anybody can explain to me what is the reason of this? Thanks!!

Comment: Yes, the number is too big.  If you need to deal with large numbers your best bet is to use some libray,. like mathjs http://mathjs.org/

Comment: Numbers lose precision when they go over 2^53 - 1

Comment: ?? Yes it is, you can open the console in a browser and execute it...

Comment: @vijoc The first line of every snippet is.

Comment: @vijoc - It is in fact valid javascript, well the `Number(12345)` part is.

Comment: Ah yes, that part is.

Comment: Here is [another explanation of the context](http://2ality.com/2012/04/number-encoding.html) by Axel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to work with such big numbers I would suggest you use some of the big integer libraries such as [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/big-integer). The reason this happens as far as I know is the way processors and memory work. It's no related to some "bug" in JS.

Answer (score 1):

Integers (numbers without a period or exponent notation) are accurate up to 15 digits. Javacript simply adds zeros to keep the number accurate in terms of its digit length.

[Documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_numbers.asp)